# ContainsValue VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary set up with the entries. I wanted to get the letter that corresponds to the value and I am a bit stuck on the coding side of it. Here is my code so far:

```
Dim chardict As New Dictionary(Of Char, Integer)
chardict.Add("A", 0)
chardict.Add("B", 1)

If chardict.ContainsValue(1) then
   Console.WriteLine(the letter that corrosponds to the value)
end if

Output: B
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like your dictionary is backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this into your IF statement:

```
 Dim Value = (From t In chardict
          Where t.Value = 1
          Select t.Key
          )

  Console.WriteLine(Value(0))
```

Comment: The parentheses around the Linq are unnecessary.